# Database design tool WP8 / Linq2SQL

Tags: c#, database, windows-phone-8, linq-to-sql

I am looking for a tool (standalone or plugin) that allows me to grahpically (similiar to the one available in Xcode for CoreData) design a database (.sdf) that I can use in my Windows Phone 8 App and then export the code to Linq2SQL.

Has any of you heard of such a tool or does anyone maybe have a better idea? I am constantly running into trouble writing the code by hand and I hope that a graphic representation will make it easier for me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Try [SQL Server Compact Toolbox](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/) SQL Server Compact Toolbox is a Visual Studio add-in and standalone app , for managing all aspects of your SQL Server Compact database files